# scanf("%f", &weight) and scanf("%f", weight) How to determine when to add prefix &

Tags: c

I read the following codes:

```
//talkback.c -- nosy, informative program
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>  //for strlen() prototype
#define DENSITY 62.4  //human density in lbs per cu ft

int main() {

    float weight, volume;
    int size, letters;
    char name[40];  //name is an array of 40 characters

    printf("Hi! What's your first name?\n");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("%s, what's your weight in pounds?\n", name);
    scanf("%f", &weight);
    size  = sizeof name;
    letters = strlen(name);
    volume = weight / DENSITY;
    printf("Well, %s, your volumn is %2.2f cubit feet.\n", name, volume);
    printf("Also, your first name has %d letters, \n", letters);
    printf("and we have %d bytes to store it.\n", size);

}
```

Run it and output:

```
In [13]: !./a.out
Hi! What's your first name?
Hery
Hery, what's your weight in pounds?
100
Well, Hery, your volumn is 1.60 cubit feet.
Also, your first name has 4 letters, 
and we have 40 bytes to store it.
```

I noticed that  `scanf("%s", name);` and `scanf("%f", &weight);` , the second has a prefix & ahead of weight.

How could I distinguish which situation to add the prefix or not?

Comment: Add it when the argument is not a pointer or array. Also, don't use `scanf`.

Comment: It the parameter is an `array`, then it is converted to a *pointer-to-type* on access, subject to the exceptions (not applicable here) set out in [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3). If it is not an array and not a pointer, then add the `'&'` to take the address of the variable providing a pointer to `scanf`.

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings and they'll tell you if you get it wrong.

Comment: Now that is always good advice (`-Wall -Wextra` minimum for gcc/clang -- or `/W3` for VS) and do not accept code until it compiles cleanly (without a single warning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf()` stands for scan formatted string. Now while scanning input from a standard `input stream`, `scanf()` needs to put that input data into somewhere. To store the formatted `input data`, `scanf()` needs to know the memory location of a variable of the same data type.
That is why `scanf()` needs a pointer (a pointer in `C` stores memory location of a variable or an expression) to store input. The `address-of operator` (&) preceeding a variable i.e. `&var` Indicates the memory location of variable 'var'.

```
int var;
scanf("%d",&var);

char str[20];
scanf("%s",str);
```

For the second example, we do not need the address-of operator because **C treats array name variable as a pointer**.

`printf()` is the reverse function of `scanf()`. It prints the formatted string to the standard output. Printf doesn't need any memory location to print the output, it only needs the variable to get the data and formats it according to the format specifier.

```
printf("%c in ASCII is %d",65,65);

The output will be: A in ASCII is 65
```

Comment: thanks for your dedicated answer. I assumed printf is abbr of print function.

Comment: "C treats array name variable as a pointer." --> No. An array is not a pointer and a pointer is not an array.  When an array is an function argument, it is converted to the type and value of the address (pointer) of the first element.  Yet other array uses exist that do not perform that conversion.

Comment: It is not said that it is a pointer. It merely says that it is interpreted as a pointer.

Comment: @chux I have taken this quote from the well-known programming site called programiz  'Arrays are closely related to pointers in C programming but the important difference between them is that a pointer variable takes different addresses as value whereas, in case of the array it is fixed.'

Comment: @rarblack The _address_ of an array is fixed.  The address of a pointer variable is also fixed.  The _value_ of an array is not fixed.  The _value_ of a pointer variable  is not fixed.  If one equates "C treats array name variable as a pointer", then it is easy to confuse one is fixed and the other changeable when they both have fixed addresses and changeable values.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you are accepting strings(ie; character arrays) you don't need `&` in front of the variable name. This is because, `scanf()` expects address of the variable. For normal variables the variable name represents its value, whereas the for an array the array name is a pointer pointing to the first element of the array. So when you say `weight` the address of the first element in the array gets substituted and you don't need to use `&`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to start from [scanf c rerefence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and pay attention to type. E.g. `%f` means type of argument `float*` - pointer to `float`. So you can use only pointer, i.e. address, and there are several way to provide address:

- if you have just variable (`float a;`) you should use `&` operator applied for variable name;
- if you have pointer (`float * ptr;` or `float arr[10];`) you can use `ptr`, or `arr`, or `(arr+4)`, etc. (all of this have type `float *`), as well as you can use `&arr[4]` (here `arr[4]` is of type `float`, but `&arr[4]` is of type `float *`)

**Note**: before using `float * ptr;` in `scanf` pointer should be initialized with valid address, e.g. `ptr = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float));`

Answer (score 1):

How about a simply example "when to add prefix &"?

`scanf("%f", ...)` expects a a following `float *`.

---

With `float weight`, `weight` is not a `float *`, but `&weight` is a `float *`.

```
float weight;
scanf("%f", &weight);  // & needed
```

---

With `float *p`, `p` is a `float *`.

```
float weight;
float *p = &weight
scanf("%f", p);  // no &
```

---

Tip: insure your compiler has all its warnings are enabled.  A well enabled compiler will report a `scanf()` specifier and argument mis-match.